# What is the dart equivalent of getScript

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-js-interop

What is the Dart equivalent of Jquery getScript (to load javascript from Dart) ?
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Dart provides a function that does this.

You can fetch the script using an HttpRequest, create a script element, add the received text to the element and then use Dart-js-Interop to call a JavaScript function.

Alternatively you can add jQuery and call `getScript` using Dart-js-Interop.